# Can anyone help me with this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have maked a little code in javascript i'm not the best at code but i have tried to make a code but it don't work

```
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var user = prompt('Your cpanel.cuccfree.com user', '');
      var web = prompt('Your cpanel domainname', 'example');
      var web2 = prompt('Your cpanel domaintype (.com/.net/..)', 'cu.cc');
      var url = "https://ifastnet.com/portal/cart.php?a=add&pid=89&configoption[193]=";
      var url2 = ".472656&sld=";
      var url3 = "&tld=";
      var url4 = "&domainoption=owndomain";
      var all = url + user + url2 + web + url3 + web2;
      var (window.open(all));
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = all;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="output"></p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Start her.</button>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to enter username and website in prompt then it should set a link with username and website

It should be set:
https://ifastnet.com/portal/cart.php?a=add&pid=89&configoption[193]=**user**.472656&sld=**web**&tld=**web2**&domainoption=owndomain

Comment: Define 'don't work'

Comment: what is your objective?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? (Hint: Yes, it does)

Comment: what you want to do with the start button?

Comment: Clearly it needs to grow up and learn some responsibility. Kick it out of the house and let it get its own apartment at the very least.

Comment: @WeeHee Please stop editing your code and first and foremost start telling us **what this does, what it doesn't do, and what you expect it to do.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this :

```
var (window.open(all));
```

to :

```
window.open(all);
```

Final code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var user=prompt('Your cpanel.cuccfree.com user',''); 
var web=prompt('Your cpanel domainname','example'); 
var web2=prompt('Your cpanel domaintype (.com/.net/..)','cu.cc'); 
var url = "https://ifastnet.com/portal/cart.php?a=add&pid=89&configoption[193]=";
var url2 = ".472656&sld=";
var url3 = "&tld="; 
var url4 = "&domainoption=owndomain"; 
var all = url + user + url2 + web + url3 + web2;
window.open(all); 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = all;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="output"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Start her.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @WeeHee ,if my post help you , mark it please.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error in this line of code
var (window.open(all)); document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = all;

a variable can't start with "("

window.open(all) 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = all;

Answer (score 0):

Remove or change this line
var (window.open(all));

Comment: This is removed and now the code is working THANK YOU

Comment: @WeeHee So what's the problem that's left now...?!